# How to have a field that has a different params value to the displayed name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a form that collects an email address.

```
  <%= form_tag accounts_path, :method => :post do %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :email %><br />
      <%= text_field_tag :homeEmail %>
    </div>
    <div class="Section-button">
      <div class="actions">
        <%= submit_tag "Update", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

I have the field tag for the email being :homeEmail because I want to recover it in the controller using params[:homeEmail].

I want to use a capybara feature spec test such as

```
  fill_in 'Email', with: user.email, match: :first
  click_button Update
```

but I receive the error:

```
Unable to find visible field "Email" that is not disabled within #<Capybara::Node::Element
```

The element is not disabled, and when I try the page in development mode it works. The test fills in the field if I just change the text_field_tag to

```
<%= text_field_tag :email %>
```

but this does not work in the controller because the params is params[:email] not params[:homeEmail].

How do I get this test working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fill_in` finds the element to fill by `name`, `id`, or associated label text.  When you're doing `fill_in 'Email', ...` I assume you're intending it to use the associated label text option. The issue you're having is that the label isn't actually associated with the field (if you look at the HTML source you'll see the labels `for` attribute doesn't match the inputs `id` attribute). The fix is to change your view to correctly associate the label with the field

```
<%= form_tag accounts_path, :method => :post do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :homeEmail, 'Email' %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :homeEmail %>
  </div>
  ...
```

Then your `fill_in 'Email', with: user.email` should work correctly

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing:

```
  fill_in 'Email', with: user.email, match: :first
```

You should do:

```
  fill_in 'homeEmail', with: user.email, match: :first
```

Since capybara tries to find an element with id or name attributes if you're doing       `<%= text_field_tag :homeEmail %>` it will generate `<input type="text" name="homeEmail" id="homeEmail">` but while filling it you're using `Email` as a selector for which capybara is not able to find any element.

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: I have upvoted this because it works and is potentially useful in other cases, but I have accepted Walpole's answer because it allows me to use the test without modification.